# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode' (django contact form)

Tags: python, django, forms, attributeerror

I am creating a Contact page for my django project. forms.py has name, subject, sender and message. Here's the view:

```
def contact(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = ContactForm()
else:
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        sender_email = form.cleaned_data['sender_email']
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']

        send_mail(subject, message, sender_email, ['***@gmail.com'])
return render(request, 'contact_us.html', {'form': form})
```

The template:

```
<h1>Contact Us</h1>
<form method="POST">
    {%csrf_token%}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

After I click Send I get this error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode' and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong despite checking other questions of the same type the last couple of days.
I have followed instructions from [link 1](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-email-contact-form) and [link 2](https://medium.com/@_christopher/how-to-send-emails-with-python-django-through-google-smtp-server-for-free-22ea6ea0fb8e) to set up the SMTP server (2 different cases) and it gives me the same error.
How can I fix that? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If anyone ever faces the same issue, check your settings.py file. It might have trailing commas. This was the issue for me.