# AttributeError 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode' during all auth login with facebook

Tags: django, heroku, facebook-login, django-allauth

I am trying to integrate the social login into my project. during login Facebook, gives the error 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'.I have used django-allauth  [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html)

and I used the Heroku go deploy projects.
[to see the error click.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XVOr.png)

Inside the database data, entry from Facebook is happening.

[to see facebook entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri9Dh.png)

any suggestions to rid of this problem.

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
                 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

django-allauth parameters from setting.py
SITE_ID = 1

```
# Provider specific settings


EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER =os.getenv('HOST_EMAIL', 'ABAC@GAIL.COM'),
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('HOST_EMAIL_PASSWORD', 'PASSWORD'),
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Concact share Team <noreply@dnyanesh.com>'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS =1
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 5
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_TIMEOUT = 86400 # 1 day. This does ot prevent admin login frombeing brut forced.
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL ='/accounts/login/' #or any other page
ACCOUNT_PRESERVE_USERNAME_CASING = False # reduces the delays in iexact lookups
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL=True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH = 5
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED =True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_VALIDATORS = None


#Account Signup
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'socialmodule.forms.SignupForm',}

Social Account Settings
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'SCOPE': ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_friends'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'INIT_PARAMS': {'cookie': True},
        'FIELDS': [
            'id',
            'email',
            'name',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'verified',
            'locale',
            'timezone',
            'link',
            'gender',
            'updated_time',
        ],
        'EXCHANGE_TOKEN': True,
        'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: 'en_US',
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
        'VERSION': 'v2.12',
    },
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    }
}
```

authentication backends used.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]
```

Third party app used in Installed app.

```
  THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',

    'rest_framework',
]
```

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Can you share the code of the view that is raising an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone ever faces the same issue, check your settings.py file. It might have trailing commas. This was the issue for me.
[similar problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421623/attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attribute-encode-django-contact-form)

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER =os.getenv('HOST_EMAIL', 'ABAC@GAIL.COM')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('HOST_EMAIL_PASSWORD', 'PASSWORD')
```

remove the training " , ".